# Dynamic object attribute names in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array like this:

```
rules[0] = "a";
rules[1] = "b";
rules[2] = "c";
```

And an object `data` that has values `value-a`, `value-b`, `value-c` (the last letter comes from "rules".

I know you might suggest an array, but I really need them to be normal attributes. How can I create these dynamic attribute names formed with the string "value-" and the value of a variable?

```
for r in rules {
  data.value-??? = "something";
}
```

Comment: data["value-" + r] = "something"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const data = rules.reduce((dict, key) => {
    dict[`value-${key}`] = 'something';
    return dict;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement, which uses the element

```js
var rules = ["a", "b", "c"],
    data = {};

for (let r of rules) {
    data['value-' + r] = "something";
}
console.log(data);
```

Or simple [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

ES6

```js
var rules = ["a", "b", "c"],
    data = {};

rules.forEach(r => data['value-' + r] = "something");
console.log(data);
```

ES5

```js
var rules = ["a", "b", "c"],
    data = {};

rules.forEach(function (r) {
    data['value-' + r] = "something"
});
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = {};
var rules = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
rules.forEach(function(rule) {
  data['value-'+rule] = "something";
});
console.log(data);
```